# Ubuntu 14.04 wi-fi disconnect

Tags: wireless, 64-bit, 14.04, lts

After Installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit , my wifi after time off, the dmesg tells me the following:

```
wlan0 : deauthenticated from 00:40:10:10:00:03 ( Reason : 7)
[ 1201.967245 ] cfg80211 : Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1201.969781 ] cfg80211 : World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1201.969784 ] cfg80211 : DFS Master region : unset
[ 1201.969786 ] cfg80211 : ( start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth) , ( max_antenna_gain , max_eirp )
[ 1201.969788 ] cfg80211 : ( 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 MBI MBM 2000 )
[ 1201.969789 ] cfg80211 : ( 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 MBI MBM 2000 )
[ 1201.969791 ] cfg80211 : ( 2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 MBI MBM 2000 )
[ 1201.969792 ] cfg80211 : ( 5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 MBI MBM 2000 )
[ 1201.969793 ] cfg80211 : ( 5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 MBI MBM 2000 )
```

My network card is this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [ 0280 ] : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [ 10ec : 8176 ] (rev 01)
Subsystem : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [ 10ec : 9181 ]
Flags: bus master , fast DEVSEL , latency 0 , IRQ 16
I / O ports at 2000 [size = 256 ]
Memory at f0500000 (64 -bit, non - prefetchable ) [size = 16K ]
Capabilities : [40 ] Power Management version 3
Capabilities : [ 50] MSI : Enable- Count = 1/1 Maskable - 64bit +
Capabilities : [70 ] Express Endpoint , MSI 00
Capabilities : [100 ] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities : [140 ] Virtual Channel
Capabilities : [160 ] Device Serial Number 01-91-81- fe- ff -4c - e0 -00
Kernel driver in use : RTL8192CE
```

I must restart the network-manager to see the wireless network again.